# Emacs EDE - Automake and the Order of Subdirectories

Tags: c++, emacs, automake

I am using Emacs with EDE.  I have a small C++ project with two subdirectories `include` and `src`.

```
project/
├── include/
└── src/
```

I have shared library targets in `include/` that are needed by program targets in `src/`.  I.e., I want to compile all targets in `include/` before I compile any target in `src/`.  At the moment, there are no targets in the project's top directory.

Initially and in the project's top directory, EDE sets the subdirs directive SUBDIRS to

```
SUBDIRS= src/ include/
```

in `Makefile.am`.  Upon compilation with `make`, the compiler complains about missing rules for the shared libraries (because they are not compiled yet).  If I manually change the directive to

```
SUBDIRS= include/ src/
```

everything works fine.

Now my question: can I handle the order of traversal of subdirectories from within Emacs with EDE?

Thanks,
Dominik

Answer (score -1):

I'd very much suggest **not** using subdirectories for automake projects to begin with. Not only you won't have rules dependency problems, but in general [recursive make is considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). Plus it's much faster not to use recursive automake.

For reference, I wrote [how to use non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) before.

Comment: Thank you.  This would certainly be a better way.  However, I guess this is not really possible with EDE.  Please correct me, if it is.  EDE naturally creates `Makefile.am` files for every subfolder and combines them with a recursive `Makefile.am` in the project's top folder.

Comment: It sounds like EDE has been created in a previous era and might be better avoided then :( If it creates a recursive build system, it's likely creating you more harm than solving problems.

Comment: You can still follow the non-recursive principle with the project subdivided into directories. I place automake snippets (e.g. plug.mk.am) into subdirs and then include them all into the top Makefile.am using the "include" directive.